# Selecting dynamic element name in CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

How to style a group of customized HTML tags (Angular.js directives) sharing the same suffix?

If there are three modal tags that are desired with the same style

```
1. <a-modal>
2. <b-modal>
3. <c-modal>
```

How do I create a selector that applies to all three without having them share a common attribute?

```
// doesn't work
[*-modal] {
  //style...
}

// would've worked with attributes:
div[modal="true"] {
  //style...
}
```

Comment: If it was an XML document, you could use [namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-namespaces-3/), which [allow constrained wildcards](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#type-nmsp). But they don't seem to work in HTML5, except perhaps for some built-in namespaces like `svg`.

Comment: How is this related to Angular?

Comment: Customized directives from Angular. I can remove that label though.

Comment: Well, there is the obvious solution of giving them a CSS class but you seem to want to avoid that for some reason.

Comment: @JonP Because my tags in Angular already have a shared suffix, to which I thought might be handy to apply a CSS selector rather than adding classes. But I can go with classes now knowing wildcard method is not meant for tag names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Angular directives, then you could use class names instead of a tag names to match your directives along with wildcard CSS selectors:

## HTML

`<div class="a-modal"></div>`

## CSS

`[class*="-modal"] {}`

## Angular

`restrict: 'C'`

---

However, I would suggest to just introduce a common CSS class for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simply:

```
a-modal, b-modal, c-modal {
  …
}
```

If you want a large number of custom HTML tags without a long comma-separated CSS selector, I would suggest `<modal type="a">`, etc. and `modal { … }`.

Comment: I was wondering if there was another way other than manually specifying the tag name. This is still helpful, thank you.

Comment: There is no tag wildcard method like your hypothetical examples.